# how to solve if a part of classname is dynamic in selenium with java?

Tags: java, selenium

(before refresh the page  the image is having classname as shown as)

```
<div class="icon-image SL_AND_ROLL"></div>
```

after some event if we refresh the webpage the image classname is as(for dynamic image)

`<div class="icon-image CLOSED"></div>`

there is no change in xpath before and after event and refresh the page

Comment: What are you trying to solve?

Comment: an image changes its state from static to dynamic ,based on data driven the icon(image) changes its state.i need to solve it in selenium

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Before refresh you had a div with some class and attributes. After refresh you have entirely different div with another class name and different attributes, the only thing before.div and after.div have in common is their place in DOM tree. How do you actually know that they are related? Answer to this question will lie in knowledge you have about your system, what rules it has and what transition you expect it to perform upon some event. There's really not enough information to say anything more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also  trace the element by partial class name, like

```
By.cssSelector(".icon-image")
```

Comment: did you mean i need to compare the css selector before and after refresh the page ?

Comment: @RamanaMuttana No, he meant that you can use selectors by static part only if you don't know about dynamic parts.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  But here i know  the static and dynamic classnames  or cssselectors before only.(the application is in vaadin framework)

Comment: @RamanaMuttana you mean that you don't know new class names at all? Then I'm afraid there's nothing we can help you with. On the other hand, if some class remains the same, then this accepted answer is your way to go.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  As i discussed in the question, i knew the classnames and css values before and after event of the image.Ex:After an event the image is changing its state.But the xpath values remains the same before and after the event ,only classnames and css values are changing .i knew those values also ,now my question is: Do i need compare the classnames or css values  before and after event ,to Test the status of the image?